# No Data Sheet with my RF Module, what can I do?

Tags: rf

I need to integrate the following RF module into my design but have been unable to find any information on the module except what is contained on the following webpage, no data sheet or other references.

**ZR-3A** - http://zabdz.en.alibaba.com/product/581899484-209746009/tiny_wireless_transmitter_receiver_ZR_3A_.html

I am using the Tiva C LaunchPad development board, and am seeking advice on how I might go about integrating this RF module with the Tiva C LaunchPad. Considering I do not have any information except for the image letting me know which are the power pins and which are the data pins and a few technical specs.

Comment: e-mail Ms. Ivy Chu.  Or better yet, look for a different module, which comes with sufficient technical info.  No datasheet = no sell.

Comment: Just adding some additional information I have discovered during my research. Some RF setups use encoding chips which are matched between the remote and the device, more details here - http://www.prlsoftware.com/remote-control-programming.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work.  You would have to try it.  It is risky, because of the lack of data.  Get a datasheet to increase your confidence.  Given the pinout and the components, it is a receiver only.  So you should find a matching transmitter.  Another risk is not being able to get it again.  My guess is that it would work like most of the other RF modules out there.

Comment: Thanks James. I actually have a remote to communicate with the receiver. The reason I am looking into this module is that it has already been integrated into many of our products and we have a bunch laying about. Unfortunately I have been unable to date to communicate with the individual who originally did this work. I am also completely new to RF. When you say it would work like most of the RF modules out there, what is the usual way...pointers to any info on the web etc would be great. My searches due to lack of knowledge in this area have not been the most productive.

Comment: For a simplified example of how these type of modules can be used, look at the VirtualWire library .  http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/  The library covers a variety of microcontrollers.  The supply and ground pins are connected as you would expect; to supply and ground.  The data pin is connected to one of the microcontroller I/O pins, usually directly.  The library then decodes the received noise or data until a valid bit pattern is detected.  The library is usually used with a transmitter running the same library.  Your existing transmitter software is unlikely to be compatible.

Comment: Thanks James, so just to clarify, it is usual for the Remote Controls to come with a c library so you can decode the signal received (by the RF receiver) into commands?

Comment: No.  Normally the engineer integrating RF modules into a design would create or select a library, according to any interoperability requirements.  e.g. they might use an existing library to maintain compatibility, or they might create an entirely new one to ensure incompatibility until someone figures it out.  The RF modules handle the point to point transfer of a binary data stream.  The application software translates commands into binary data, or vice versa.  The VirtualWire library is packet oriented, but some applications may require continuous transmission.

Comment: Understood, but it up to the remote control to package the message/commands and send it? Also, do you program the remotes to send certain commands or do they come with presets/defaults which you then use in your design...or both?

Comment: A remote control is a keyboard, a microcontroller, and a transmitter.  An infra-red remote control uses an IR LED as transmitter.  An RF remote control would use a radio transmitter, sometimes as a module.  The software in the microcontroller would package the commands and provide the binary data stream to the module.  If the remote control was not built by you, then you'll need specifications on it before you can use it.  Yes, there are remote controls that are pre-assembled for this, and you would use the specifications to understand what commands to check for.

Comment: Thanks James, I am now well informed and understand how these things work.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of well documented RF modules out there. This isn't one of them.

Unless your goal is a great reverse engineering blog post, you would probably do well to switch to one of the more documented parts.

That being said, start with UART and work your way through as many of the standard two wire interfaces as possible with the equipment you have. You may be pleasantly surprised.